# display: block; doesn't do the job

Tags: css, display

in a `css` file, `display: block` applied to 2 `span`s doesn't put them on separate lines, but just put them one top of each other. could you help me figure it out, please?

the problem is in selectors `.heading-primary--main` and `.heading-primary--sub`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  /* we want no default margin or sizing applied by browsers */
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /*borders and paddings are not added to the total width and height of a box*/
}

body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  /* we specify a general font that all the other children will inherit */
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.7px;
  color: #777;
  padding: 30px;
  /* adds a nice white border to entire website */
}


/* class selector */

.header {
  height: 95vh;
  /* height is 95% of the viewport(screen) */
  background-image: linear-gradient( to right bottom, rgba(126, 213, 111, 0.8), #28b485), url('../img/hero.jpg');
  /* 2 bckgr imgs, one a gradient going from left top to right bottom, opacity 0.8 */
  background-size: cover;
  /* cover will scale the image to the size of the screen */
  background-position: top;
  /* as the screen size changes, image stays the same at top and gets cropped at                            the bottom */
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 75vh, 0 100%);
  /* start with the left top corner of polygon and keep it as reference to trace the other corners of the polygon  using x, y axis */
  position: relative;
}

.logo-box {
  position: absolute;
  /* we use top, right, bottom, left to set the absolute position taking as reference the parent element (.header)*/
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
}

.logo {
  height: 35px;
  /* the width will scale accordinglly */
}

.text-box {
  position: absolute;
  /* shift 50% from top and left relative to the parent(header) */
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  /* then transform-translate 50% same directions, now in relation to the box itself */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.heading-primary {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.heading-primary--main {
  display: block;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 35px;
}

.heading-primary--sub {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 14.7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo-box">
    <img src="./img/logo-white.png" alt="logo white" class="logo" />
  </div>
  <div class="text-box">
    <h1 class="heading-primary">
      <span class="heading-primary--main">Outdoor</span>
      <span class="heading-primary--sub">is where life happens</span>
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the `line-height: 1.7px` rule on the body is causing the issue, maybe you meant just `line-height: 1.7` (without unit). Anyway, why all these `absolute` positioning.

Comment: yes, that's it. thanks. it's a learning project, it starts absolute, but it will evolve.

Comment: great, good luck !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly remove the `line-height: 1.7px;` property from the `body` in the CSS file, the overlapping issue will be solved. If you still want to use `line-height` property, I will suggest you to change from `1.7px` to `1.7`, or you can use other property value (Please refer to the provided link in below).

Different property value for `line-height`:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_line-height&preval=3

Information for `line-height` property: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp